# Words not between odds

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I have strings like :

"article.DOS = 998 and article.des = 'toto.tata' or article.des = "ot.o""

NB : the whole string is a single string.

I'd like to put every word.word in upper case, but not words beginning and ending with ' or "

My current regex is : `Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\S+\.\S+");`

In the end, my string should be :

"ARTICLE.DOS = 998 and ARTICLE.DES = 'toto.tata' or ARTICLE.DES = "ot.o""

To make it in upper case, I use :

```
private static string MeToUpper(Match m)
{
    return m.Value.ToUpper();
}

internal string ToUpper(string codeSql)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\S+\.\S+");
    return rgx.Replace(codeSql, new MatchEvaluator(MeToUpper));
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `[\w\S_-]` could be abbreviated to `\S`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    private static string MeToUpper(Match m)
    {
        return ((m.Value[0] != '\'') && (m.Value[0] != '\"'))
            ? m.Value.ToUpper()
            : m.Value;
    }

    internal static string ToUpper(string codeSql)
    {
        Regex rgx = new Regex("(\'|\")?\\S+\\.\\S+");
        return rgx.Replace(codeSql, new MatchEvaluator(MeToUpper));
    }
```

Comment: thanks, but I See I misspoke : my string is a single string : "article.DOS = 998 and article.des = 'toto.tata' or article.des = "ot.o"".

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
var s = @"article.DOS = 998 and article.des = 'toto.tata' or article.des = ""ot.o""";
var upper = new Regex(@"[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\s+[^""']", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
    .Replace(s, m => m.Value.ToUpper());
```

> => "ARTICLE.DOS = 998 and ARTICLE.DES = 'toto.tata' or ARTICLE.DES = "ot.o"

Comment: No, there's not necessarily a space after word.word

Comment: Thought so. Now it handles that.

Comment: Thanks, but the strings can also be : "article.DOS,article.REF , ..."

Comment: It's starting to sound like you need a parser and not a regular expression.